# c# run time error message

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I keep getting an error that i don't understand. Must declare the scalar variable "@q"

Tens of hours of research, tried multiple solutions without success.

```
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(
    "UPDATE Stockmaster SET Curbalqty=@q WHERE Stockno= @Stockno");
cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stockno", s);
cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@q", q);                                        

sc.Connection = con;
sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding parameters to `cmnd` you should add them to `sc`

Try this

```
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Stockmaster SET Curbalqty=@q WHERE Stockno= @Stockno");
sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stockno", s);
sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@q", q);

sc.Connection = con;

con.Open();
sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

In addition to that your connection is not being `Open` before calling `ExecuteNonQuery` you should do `con.Open();` for that.

A more resource friendly code would look like this below:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
{
   using (SqlCommand sc = new 
    SqlCommand("UPDATE Stockmaster SET Curbalqty= @q WHERE Stockno= @Stockno"))
   {
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stockno", s);
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@q", q);

        sc.Connection = con;

        con.Open();
        sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
   }
}
```

Comment: At least put a using() block in there.....

Comment: Beat me to it. This certainly looks like it should do the trick though it is worth noting that we have no idea if con might already have been opened so the `con.Open();` and `con.Close();` may not be necessary here.

Answer (score -1):

Use `sc` instead of 'cmnd'. And try removing the @ symbol from the following lines:

```
sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stockno", s);
sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@q", q);
```

And do the following:

```
sc.Parameters.Add("Stockno", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = s;
sc.Parameters.Add("q", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = q;
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to add the datatype

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
        command.Parameters.Add("@Stockno", SqlDbType.Int);
        command.Parameters["@@Stockno"].Value = customerID;
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
        SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Stockmaster SET Curbalqty= " + @q + " WHERE Stockno= " + @Stockno);
                cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stockno", s);
                cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@q", q);




                sc.Connection = con;
                sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Explination of downvotes? I believe this solves the OP's question.

Comment: You believe incorrectly. Where is `@q` defined? Also string concatentatikon for SQL queries is a very bad practice. You've also missed the use of `cmnd` instead of `sc`.

Comment: Oh derp it was a typo